# "performBlockAndWait:" block is not executed

Tags: ios, core-data, concurrency, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a method similar to this:

```
- (void)handleUpdate
{
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSArray *objectIDs = [self.objectsInMainContext valueForKeyPath:@"objectID"];

      [self.privateContext performBlockAndWait: ^{
         // Some processing
      }];
   });
}
```

What I called `mainContext` is associated to main queue, and `privateContext` is associated to a private queue and is child of the `mainContext`. This method is called from the `privateContext`'s private queue, and it is not `nil` when the `performBlockAndWait:` call is reached, but execution does not enter the block and neither any code after this method is reached...

What could I be missing here?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** I get no error in Xcode, the breakpoints I've set in the code inside the `performBlockAndWait:` block and after this method call are simply not reached.

**EDIT 2:** I corrected the code snippet, I wasn't accessing the `mainContext` but an array of objects associated to `mainContext`.

Comment: Any specific reason why you got to the main context to get the object IDs when you are already in the private context in the first place?

Comment: @Mundi sorry, that line is wrong... I edit the question

Comment: @Mundi I need to pass the objects I got in `mainContext` to this child context to perform my updates.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, there is at least 1 thing that is wrong in your situation:

Calling `performBlockAndWait:` on the main thread (via passing it to the main queue). The documentation says that `performBlockAndWait:`

> Synchronously performs a given block on the receiver’s queue.

As a result of that call, you will get a dead lock on the main thread (as you use `dispatch_sync` outside.

UPDATE on the `dispatch_async` way:
The problem will not disappear. That's because you'll be still using the main queue (which implies the main thread in the end) and the main CD context (which also implies the main thread). The problem is that you make the main thread to wait until the job is done on the same (main) thread - just a dead lock out of the box.

Comment: Since I need to access `objectIDs` inside the block, which should be the best approach: calling `handleUpdate` from an async thread different from the `privateContext`'s private queue, or using `dispatch_async` for getting the main thread?

Comment: I doubt using a synchronous method is required. But if it is, just remove the enclosing dispatch_sync - but initialize your context with NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType instead (using - (instancetype)initWithConcurrencyType:(NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType)type).

Comment: I use the `dispatch_async` to get the main queue because I need to access main context's objects, and mai context is associated to main thread...

Comment: I just tried changing the `dispatch_sync` for a `dispatch_async` and the problem seems to persist

Answer (score 0):

If `handleUpdate` is called from the private queue as you say, then this is a classic deadlock.

You call `dispatch_sync` on the private queue. That means "wait until this returns before continuing on this queue." Then, inside that block, you enqueue another block that has to wait to run on the private queue and won't return until it does. The queue is now waiting on itself and will never progress.

I suspect you want `dispatch_sync` to be `dispatch_async` here.

Comment: But I need to access `objectIDs` array inside the block, don't may using `dispatch_async` cause problems then?

Comment: Would it be better to call `handleUpdate` from an async thread different from the privateContext's private queue, instead of using `dispatch_async` there to get the main queue?

Comment: I don't think there's a single answer here. You need to manage your concurrency across the app. Make sure you've started with the Core Data Concurrency section though: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Concurrency.html. Typically you want to let Core Data handle the concurrency via `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, not try to force specific queues on it.

Comment: I initialize the `privateContext` with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType`, but my `mainContext` is associated to main thread, and I need to get its objects from `privateContext`... that's why firstly I access main context's objects from main queue, and then I try to perform the block for the private context in its private queue...

Comment: It seems that changing the `dispatch_sync` for a `dispatch_async` does not solve my scenario...

Answer (score 0):

You have several problems.

First, you are using GCD directly to serialize access to a `NSMainQueueConcurrency` MOC.  You should **never** use anything but the CoreData synchronization mechanisms for accessing CoreData.  Yes, it is safe to access a `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType` MOC from the main thread.  However, you should never use GCD directly... especially `dispatch_sync`.

Second, you are using `dispatch_sync` which is not reentrant.  It can, and will, cause deadlocks.  You should hardly ever use this function.  Consider it a very sharp instrument, to be used where it is the only solution to a very specific problem.

Third, you are calling `performBlockAndWait` on a child context, which should never be done because it can cause deadlocks.  In general, you should avoid the non-asynchronous threading models unless you really know what you are doing.

Your code should be something more like this.  Each `performBlock` call will post a block onto a message queue, which will get processed independently of any waiting thread.

```
- (void)handleUpdate
{
    [self.mainContext performBlock:^{
        NSArray *objectIDs = [self.objectsInMainContext valueForKeyPath:@"objectID"];
        [self.privateContext performBlock: ^{
            // Some processing with objectIDs
        }];
    });
}
```